# sendTextMessage() with intent -- identifying which message?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-pendingintent

Looking at many examples on sent and delivery intents, e.g.:

[Android SMS Message delivery report intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875354/android-sms-message-delivery-report-intent)

, they all seem to just report that **some** message was successfully sent or not sent, not **which** message.

To explain: If I send two messages really quickly after one another, and when the broadcast receivers trigger -- how can I know which one  it triggered for?

Does the radio operate in such a manner that only a single message can be sent, and then a confirmation must be received with a delivery status before the next message is sent?

Why does Android documentation not point this out? What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

For each message you send, you can provide a `PendingIntent` which is triggered when the message is sent and/or when the message is delivered. You can put anything you want in the `PendingIntent` to indicate which message it was: an "extra", or an "action" or whatever. There are numerous posts on Stackoverflow that show how to do this.